# Load a function after the user closed a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert2

I'm using a library called SweetAlert. I want to load a function after the user closed the modal.

My code currently:

```
Swal.fire({
   imageUrl: 'https://placeholder.pics/svg/600x600',
   imageWidth: 600,
   imageHeight: 600,
   confirmButtonText: 'Jai compris'
}).then(('load', function (event) {

   var $this = $(this);
   $this.text('...');
   var $imageSection = $this.closest('.image-section');
   var $colorThiefOutput = $imageSection.find('.color-thief-output');
   var $targetimage = $imageSection.find('.target-image');
   showColorsForImage($targetimage, $imageSection);
}));
```

The console.log:

`the variables are not defined`

the code working with a click on a button :

```
Swal.fire({
   imageUrl: 'https://placeholder.pics/svg/600x600',
   imageWidth: 600,
   imageHeight: 600,
   confirmButtonText: 'jai compris'
}).then((result) => {
   $('.run-functions-button').click('load', function (event) {
      //Swal.fire('Any fool can use a computer')
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.text('...');
      var $imageSection = $this.closest('.image-section');
      var $colorThiefOutput = $imageSection.find('.color-thief-output');
      var $targetimage = $imageSection.find('.target-image');
      showColorsForImage($targetimage, $imageSection);
   });
});
```

My question is why my variables are not defined? The click on a button is an obligation to load a function?

Comment: Which variables are not defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Swal.fire({
   imageUrl: 'https://placeholder.pics/svg/600x600',
   imageWidth: 600,
   imageHeight: 600,
   confirmButtonText: 'Jai compris'
}).then(('load', function (event) {

   var $this = $('.run-functions-button');
   $this.text('...');
   var $imageSection = $this.closest('.image-section');
   var $colorThiefOutput = $imageSection.find('.color-thief-output');
   var $targetimage = $imageSection.find('.target-image');
   showColorsForImage($targetimage, $imageSection);
}));
```